# How to tell if a task was started by another task

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I need to find if a thread if a child of another thread.

Below is an oversimplified example of what I am trying to do, but basically I need to tell if a task is a child of another task.

If I have a function that starts a couple of tasks...

```
_task1 = FuncA();
_task2 = FuncA();
```

And within that function, it start another task

```
public async Task FuncA()
{
  // do something
  await Task.Delay(500, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // then call the other function
  await FuncB().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task FuncB()
{
  // now check for the 'parent'
  if( IsChildTask(_task1) ) // <--- something similar 
  {
    // child of first task
  }
}
```

I know that the current `thread id` would have changed, (because async/await) 
Is it possible to tell if a current task/context/thread is a child of another thread?.

Comment: `Task FuncB(bool isChild=false)` seems like the easiest solution

Comment: That said this very much smells of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: No, because, (in my simplified example), `FuncA()` is created exactly the same way. And both of them start `FuncB()`, but how can I tell if it was 'created' from `_task1` or `_task2`?

Comment: You want to do something with parent task or only know which task is parent?

Comment: I only want to know which task is the parent, I don't want to do anything with it other than knowing if the current task is a child of another, (to use a parent/child terminology).

Comment: There is no way to "identify" a `Task`s parent, Tasks don't hold this information. Also bear in mind that Task may switch `Thread` at any point (kinda) so you can't rely on the Thread id either. You need to remember that a `Task` is conceptual and not a physical thing, unlike `Thread`. You could potentially write some kind of wrapper that would hold an id ([Tasks do have ids](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.id?view=netframework-4.7.2)) but then you'd need to somehow manage all these yourself. I still think this is an XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned, I know that the thread id changes, it was in my post. And repeating "XY Problem" does not make it one, I would suggest you read the definition of what an "XY Problem" actually is.

Comment: @SimonGoodman "XY problem" means, that you are asking about problem "X" (in this case, how to identify the genealogy of a given task) because you think it is the best way to solve problem "Y" (which you have not yet stated).  Liam is calling "XY Problem" because if some function needs to behave differently depending on which task/thread called it (or in this case, on which task/thread _created_ the task/thread that called it), that can be big red warning of a possible bad design.

Comment: Thanks, I am familiar with that analogy, but as I said in my original post, "_.. oversimplified example of what I am trying to do_". In order to try and ask a question in a simple clear way I have to simplify the example. 
To me the question was straight forward enough "_how to identify the genealogy of a given task_", without having to get into great details of the actual problem.

Comment: Maybe using `AsyncLocal` to set some contextual information before calling `FuncB`?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution, just tell who is caller

```
private string task1Name = "task1";
private string task2Name = "task2";

_task1 = FuncA(task1Name );
_task2 = FuncA(task2Name );

public async Task FuncA(sting taskName)
{
  // do something
  await Task.Delay(500, CancellationToken.None).ConfigureAwait(false);

  // then call the other function
  await FuncB(taskName).ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public async Task FuncB(string parentName)
{
  // now check for the 'parent'
  if( parentName == task1Name ) // <--- something similar 
  {
    // child of first task
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for something a little bit more generic.
My over simplified example only had one task, but my actual code could have multiple child of child tasks...